# How do I invalidate a specific objective-c observer

Tags: objective-c

How do I remove a specific observer in objective-c? I have several observers using the defaultCenter. When the view disappears I'm calling:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

This appears to not remove the observers and they're getting duplicated. Wondering how I could keep a reference of an observer for error checking to see if it exists. This is how I'm creating my observers.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateChart)
                                             name:@"UPDATECHART"
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: When are you calling `addObserver`?  It might be a good idea to log messages when those two statements execute to be sure they're paired correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing `self`, try the below code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"UPDATECHART" 
                                              object:nil];
```

Comment: I was on vacation so I'm just getting back to this issue. This seemed to resolve the issue I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should double-check that the removeObserver message really gets sent. Apple's documentation clearly states that

*Removes all the entries specifying a given observer from the receiver’s dispatch table.*

Are you sure that `self` is the same object? Might make sense to check that this is the same pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting duplicate observers, this simply proves that *you* are calling `addObserver:self` when there is *already* an observer. You need to figure out why that is. I'm betting it's because `self` is *leaking* — it is not going out of existence when you think it is. Thus you have multiple instances of whatever class `self` represents, floating around persistently, all staying registered and all being notified.

You can easily prove or disprove that hypothesis by logging `self` in `updateChart`, because logging provides a unique identifier (the memory address). If you see at least two different unique identifiers, you've got multiple copies of this class persisting simultaneously.

(Note too that in modern Foundation code there is *no need* to call `removeObserver`; the observer is ARC-weak referenced and can go out of existence without ill effect. To that extent, the question of `removeObserver` being called is a red herring.]